# Yii HAS_MANY Relationship with Non Foreign Key and Non Primary Key

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a following code:

```
        $country = CountryCodes::model()->with(
            [
                'country_subdivisions' => [
                     CountryCodes::HAS_MANY,
                    'CountrySubDivision',
                    ['country_subdivisions.iso2'=>'t.iso2']
                ]
            ]
        )->findByPk($id);
        $states = $country->country_subdivisions;
```

I have 2 models/tables CountryCodes and CountrySubDivision. Both table has iso2 column. I want to get the related Subdivision for a Country By ID.

I am not sure why am i getting the following Error:

**Relation "country_subdivisions" is not defined in active record class "CountryCodes".**

I am a newbie in Yii Framework and I'm using Yii 1.1.x and php 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you need to define a relationship by overriding [`relations()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail) method in CountryCodes class.

```
public function relations() {
    $relations                 = [
        'country_subdivisions' => [
            CountryCodes::HAS_MANY,
            'CountrySubDivision',
            [
                'iso2'         => 'iso2'
            ]
        ]
    ];
    // merge with parents 
    return CMap::mergeArray(
        parent::relations(),
        $relations
    );
}
```

Then, you can :

```
$country = CountryCodes::model()->with('country_subdivisions')->findByPk($id);
$states  = $country->country_subdivisions;
```

Comment: Thanks For your input , it works like a charm now.

But My Class hierarchy was like this:
BaseCountryCode
   -CountryCodes

I had put my relations method in to the base class. I beleived the public function "relations" would be accessible to the child class. It didn't work so i tried to use the syntax above..anyway thanks alot.

Comment: @sdhakal When you define the relationship in BaseCountryCode class, You just return parent::relations() in CountryCodes class. like <br/>public function relations() {
    parent::relations();
}

Comment: Yup, true, i did the same and it works perfectly fine.. Thanks